# How do I get my podcast feed created?

Tags: rss, podcasting

I have a wordpress site. I added a plugin to create podcasts. It is the Blubrry PowerPress plugin. Then I uploaded an mp3 to my site. Then I used to plugin to display the podcast.

[Here is an example page where the podcast is](http://glowingstart.com/great-business-idea-sure-next/), at the very bottom.

But when I go to this url to find my feed: http://glowingstart.com/feeds/podcast/

I get a 404-error.

Would anyone know why that happens? And how do I determine whether my feed url has been created and the feed updated?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched and/or asked in [the plugin's support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/powerpress)?

Comment: The feed works fine for me as well !!

Answer (score 1):

The URL you provided works fine for me: [Link](http://glowingstart.com/feeds/podcast/)

This returns the correct feed. you may have had some WordPress caching happening, which prevented the feed from being returned, but it's working now.

Comment: http://glowingstart.com/feeds/podcast/ doesn't work for me, but **http://glowingstart.com/feed/podcast/** does.  Note that the latter uses `/feed/`, not `/feeds/`.